# HTML5 official examples for e-commerce

Tags: html, e-commerce, online-store

While building a new onlineshop (based on magento) we considered to make use of the new HTML5 tags like `<header><footer><section><article>` etc.

We read lots of blogs / websites describing how to use the tags - unfortunately, most of the time the authors use Blogs or News Sites for their examples but not a typical e-commerce shop with landing-pages, category pages, product pages.

Also, we found some shops that are using the above-mentioned tags already - but they do differently.

Therefore we would like to know if someone knows if there are any (maybe official) examples of how to structure e.g. category- or product pages with HTML5-Tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many HTML5 tags have their own semantic meaning and are self-explanatory. There are no hard-and-fast rules.

`<figure>` is for an image or diagram.

`<section>` is for a section or category, etc.

There aren't really any standards, other than trying to be logical in your choice of tag. While you can find [examples](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-single-product-page/) of how people are using them, in the bigger scheme of things, it doesn't matter all that much. **What matters is what drives customers to make purchases and having a decent structure to support SEO.**

If you really want to get into semantic markup that can actually be used (such as in Google Offers) then you may want to consider a micro-format schema as an alternative.

http://schema.org/Product